# Where should I put my system databases in WindowsCore container

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers, windows-server

We're looking into migrating our SQL Server environment to use containers.

I've successfully built a WindowsCore image with SQL Server installed. The instance is accessible with the data files using volumes so that they persist.

My question is where should I put my system databases? Im thinking externally so that things like logins etc persist, and Ill just have to put a startup procedure to `if serverproperty('Machinename') <> @@servername usp_dotheservernamething;`, but is that wise?

If I put it in the image, I still would need to rename the server, but then I suppose if I start a new container in lets say a dev environment, I wouldn't have to worry about a drive.

Thinking out loud, I could possibly add onto the startup procedure to have to change the system database mappings if the servername is a production db name? That way if we spin up a dev/qa/local container it will have system databases, but if its production it will go to the external volume for its databases...